# NaN output from Dense layer

Tags: keras

I am trying to train a simple neural net on few instances that have many features. I have 8 instances to train on, and 3 to test on (I know, this is very little, but makes sense for my application). Each instance has 4212 features which are floats ranging anywhere from 0 -> in the 1000s. When inputting these tensors into my first dense layer the layer outputs all NaN values.

I have tried changing the loss functions/optimizer/accuracy/activation functions and have not been able to gain anything but NaN output from my first dense layer.

here is my code that builds and fits the model. I have attached the output that shows tensor input and output as well as what my data looks like.

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=4212, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(25, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=150, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

And then here is what my data looks likes, as well the outputs from each tensor:

Training Data

```
[[ 0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00 ...  1.43e+00 -1.24e-01 -7.60e-01]
 [ 1.27e+02  2.00e+00  2.00e+00 ...  2.40e-01 -1.90e-02 -3.90e-01]
 [ 2.80e+02  4.00e+00  4.00e+00 ...  1.29e+00  1.65e-01  1.62e+00]
 [ 4.21e+02  4.00e+00  4.00e+00 ...  7.70e-01  9.00e-03  2.10e-01]
 [ 5.81e+02  5.00e+00  5.00e+00 ...  9.90e-01  6.40e-02  5.30e-01]]

[50. 90. 92. 71. 67.]
```

Validation Data

```
[[ 1.276e+03  1.000e+00  1.000e+00 ...  6.700e-01 -3.600e-02 -4.100e-01]
 [ 0.000e+00  0.000e+00  0.000e+00 ...  1.000e-02  3.000e-03  4.700e-01]
 [ 0.000e+00  0.000e+00  0.000e+00 ...  1.000e+00 -2.500e-02 -3.400e-01]]
[54.  2.  3.]
```

Tensors input:

```
[[ 1.276e+03  1.000e+00  1.000e+00 ...  6.700e-01 -3.600e-02 -4.100e-01]
 [ 0.000e+00  0.000e+00  0.000e+00 ...  1.000e-02  3.000e-03  4.700e-01]
 [ 0.000e+00  0.000e+00  0.000e+00 ...  1.000e+00 -2.500e-02 -3.400e-01]]
[[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
  nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
  nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
  nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
  nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
  nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
  nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]]
[[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
  nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
  nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
  nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]]
```

I am trying to use vectors that represent the stats for a player in the MLB for one season to predict the amount of runs they score the next season. I expect poor accuracy now, but I intend to add LSTM layers and train on more players careers later.

Here is more code as to how I am obtaining tensor outputs

```
intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model.input,
                                 outputs=model.layers[layer_name].input)
    intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(V_data)
    print (intermediate_output)
    intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model.input,
                                 outputs=model.layers[1].input)
    intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(V_data)
    print (intermediate_output)
    intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model.input,
                                 outputs=model.layers[2].input)
    intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(V_data)
    print (intermediate_output)
    print(model.summary())
```

Comment: You only have 5 samples to learn from and way too many features and hidden neurons. Also, please share your code that produces what you're calling "Tensors input".

Comment: Softmax with only one neuron makes no sense, as it will produce constant 1.0 output.

Comment: @highBandWidth I have edited to show more code

Comment: I faced the same problem as you did with a model consisting of 2 Dense layers with kernel_initializer='random_normal'. When I printed output of each layers before fitting, it had nan at 2 Dense layers. Have you fixed this problem?